# Prism 7 Register Multiple DialogWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I want to have 2 types of dialog windows that hosts the view for example one with `WindowStyle=ToolWindow` and another `WindowStyle=None` and a way to indicate which to resolve I thought of doing like this in the `UserControl` that i want to host:

```
      this.Loaded += delegate
        {
            var window = Window.GetWindow(this);
            window.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.ToolWindow;

        }
```

but i also want to set things like `AllowsTransparency` which can only be set before initialized

Comment: What exactly is your problem and what does this have to do with prism?

Comment: I'm using the `IDialogService` and registering my dialog window like this `containerRegistry.RegisterDialogWindow<MyDialogWindow>()` and I want to able to register more then one window and say when calling dialogService.Show() which window to wrap it in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your problem you don't need to use `containerRegistry.RegisterDialogWindow` at all.

Just look into release notes https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/releases/tag/v7.2.0.1367 and find out an example with title "Style the DailogWindow".

You should configure windows-style for each UserControl dialog inside your View using Dialog.WindowStyle attached property:

```
<prism:Dialog.WindowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="Window">
        <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="ToolWindow" />
        <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="False" />
    </Style>
</prism:Dialog.WindowStyle>
```